# Render on texture with alpha 0 for the background colour

Tags: opengl, rendering, alpha

Sorry if the question is stupid but I am very new to opengl.

I render on a target a scene with a couple of object on a background that is nothing more than the clear colour (which is 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0). 
 When I access the texture again every single pixel has 1 has alpha, how can I make sure the background has 0.0 ?

Thank you

Faye

Comment: Does your FBO have alpha? How are you accessing it? glReadPixels?

Comment: Are you calling `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` at the beginning of each frame?  Did you set your clear color with `glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);` ?